# Is there a maximum limit to listview or gridview?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

Is there a limit in rows in listview, or rows and columns in the case of gridview, that could slow down the app?

I'm looking at, a maximum nearly 5,000 individual datas with at least 3 table attributes to be displayed in each row of the listview.

Comment: a ListCiew can have max 2,147,483,648 items

Answer (score 1):

It depends of how much information you are putting in each cell (if your cell contains images, for example, it obviously will take more memory). It also depends if the phone has more or less memory (the application heap is variable).

And most important, it depends if you are recycling views (see [How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works))